# Is it possible to re-use headers in Paw?

Tags: paw-app

I'm creating a group of queries that will all share the exact same set of headers.

Is it possible to create the group of headers once and then copy/paste them to other queries? Or, even better, can I assign a known group of headers to multiple queries?

Comment: You can set single key value elements in an environment and then reuse these so that you can change them all at once later, but as far as I can tell there's nothing about groups of headers.

Comment: @KilianKoeltzsch I couldn't find it either; the app developers ask us to submit queries to SO (http://luckymarmot.com/paw/support), although I did email them to point out that Apple SE is the more applicable place. I'm hoping this might become a feature request...

Comment: Please ask the question on SO (as recommended by the developers), there are a bunch of question about paw already there and you will get faster responds than here (where we didn't even have a tag yet)

Comment: I asked about this in Meta (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252360/are-there-any-guidelines-around-which-se-site-should-host-a-given-question-tag?noredirect=1#comment824183_252360), and since it's a dev tool I guess we should move it there. I think we need a `paw-app` tag created over on SO, though

Comment: @Jedidja thanks for asking on Meta about the tags. I edited all questions to use "paw-app".

Comment: @Micha Mazaheri - We're 6 years down the line from you making it a priority, is there any sign of this getting done? Seems that the pace of dev on Paw in general has reached a glacial pace and I'm on look out for something else now myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do so is to have an environment domain for that. Make one variable per header, you may have a variable called `Content-Type` (as an example) and give it the `application/json` value for one environment, or `application/xml` for another environment. This way you'll be able to switch between JSON and XML in many requests at once.

[image: Example of using Paw environments to switch headers]

In the example above, there are 2 variables set, one for the `Content-Type` and another one for `Accept`. Both variable are then used in the request. As you can see in the preview at the bottom, the variables are replaced by their values in the HTTP request.

Comment: I understand we can set environment variables, but when I create a new request, I want to have a group of headers (all with the same value) automatically added. Basically, given an environment, I would like to have several headers (including values) assigned to the request. Creating environment variables still means I have to manually add the headers one-by-one to the request.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that. I guess then, I'll take it as a feature request. It would definitively be nice to have :) For a long time, I wanted to have request groups be able to add default Headers or even URL Parameters. I guess associating default headers to environments would be awesome! Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I'll accept the answer as  "no, there is currently no way to do this, but it may happen in the future" :) Thanks for listening!

Comment: Or "here's a workaround until it gets properly added" :D thanks!

Comment: I really wish for this request. Just trying to hack my .paw file to copy headers over. I get so fat only to realised that each header can only has one parent(request) regardless of the content it link to(environment). I'm having 10 headers that need to be copy over to 9 requests. I'm pondering if I should just copy the request itself then paste over the body and url.

Comment: Editing .paw files manually is such a mess. I'll make a batch update feature a priority!

Comment: @MichaMazaheri did you add a way to update paw file easily as you mentioned?

Comment: @MichaMazaheri do you have any news on this? It would be awesome! :)

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but still relevant. The answer still appears to be no, and hopefully @Micha Mazaheri still intends to implement it.

As an alternative, I create a Group called "_templates", then I'll have one request for logical request type. For example I will have a request with Auth headers set, or one for simple guest routes.

When it comes time for a new request, I simply right click and duplicate.

[image]

[image]